# How to get all the merge commits of branch B merged into branch A?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a master branch and two branches derived from it: A and B. Then branch B was merged into the branch A multiple times.
Is there a way to get SHAs of all the merge commits of B into A? I need this in order to revert all those merge commits.

I've tried this and it works, but only because there are commit messages that contain the branch name like *'Merge branch B into A'*.

```
git log --merges --oneline --first-parent A | grep 'B'
```

Is there a way to achieve the same without relying on the commit messages?

Comment: Have you considered rebasing interactively to keep only the commits from `B` and have a cleaner branch instead of reverting each commit?

Comment: You will need to consider how to identify those commits, as commits do not retain any information about which branch they came from, other than anything you put into the commit message of the merge. In other words, if you made 2 merges from B into A, and the first of those two merges doesn't say anything about the name of the branch, you cannot be sure that commit came from B, or that it came from C and C was then subsequently used as the base of B.

Comment: Now, all of this is "in the general sense", *you*, as in *you the human*, can go look at the commit history and find comments, issue numbers, etc. that would give you all the commits that you deem *must have* been a part of B. But I fear that unless you have a very simple commit graph, tasking git with figuring out this for you is going to be a lot harder than just looking at the git history yourself.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen thanks! Your first comment proves that I need solely rely on the commits' comments. So I did everything in the right way and that's great.